# Django migration discovery - get migrations from a different directory

Tags: python, django, migration, django-migrations

Lets say i have the same django project (multi-tenant project) in different code version, `version a` and newer `version b`. `version b` has some new migrations. I'm currently running `version a` on my production environment and want only to migrate the DB to the new version (the migrations are as such that it won't cause problems for `version a` to run correctly). so up until now, i would clone the repository with the new `version b` and run on it `manage.py migrate` and all is well. 
The problem is that now, `version a` can make new tenants (which means new schemas). - each new schema runs the migrations of the current version so in potential, there is a situation where a schema is created with the migrations of `version a` although `version b` ran its migrations and the DB is one step ahead. 
**Looking for:**
I would like to have a configuration so that the command `migrate_schemas` of the `manage.py` of `version a` will migrate against the code base of `version b`. Is this possible?

**Tech stuff**

- Django 1.8
- django-tenants 1.1.7
- python 2.7.6

Thanks!